MySQL: How to pull in values from 2 different tables in one row?
If I also want to pull form.form_name into my results on the same row, how would I adjust my query below? The form_id in the form table = the form_id in the form_version table. I also need to filter on only those records where form.removed=0
select display_name, version_num, from form_version where form_version_id in (select form_version_id from form_version where active = 1);
Tried everything I know to try.

that's called a join.

You haven't shown any schema, so we can only guess, but search for SQL tutorial on joins.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See photo for the table Schema

How does this look? (I needed some additional info from the tables, but didn't mention them for simplicity sake)
SELECT 
    database(), 
    @site_status, 
    fv.display_name, 
    fv.version_num, 
    fv.form_engine, 
    f.form_name 
FROM 
    form_version fv
JOIN 
    form f ON fv.form_id = f.form_id 
WHERE 
    fv.form_version_id IN (
        SELECT form_version_id 
        FROM form_version 
        WHERE active = 1 
          AND form_engine != 'NT'
          AND f.removed=0
    );
    

